# PHP $_GET .htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/ test.php
RewriteRule ^test/success/ test.php?success
```

test.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['success']))
    echo "SUCCESS";
else
{
    echo "nothing is set";
}
?>
```

When I try to access `test.php` like `/test.php?success` it works and echos "SUCCESS". I want it to work the same way but overwritten in htaccess. I just want it to echo that message when I open it like `/test/success/`. If it is possible, is it correct?

Comment: The first rule is likely being processed first and preventing the second rule from matching. Try swapping their order or add a `$` after `^test/` in the first rule so that it won't match if there is more than just `test/` in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess rewrite rules are read from the top to bottom,

If we apply this to your input string, we get

- start with `/test/success/`
- matches `RewriteRule ^test/ test.php` so it becomes `test.php`
- `test.php` doesn't match `RewriteRule ^test/success/ test.php?success`

We end up with `test.php`.

However, this isn't what you want, because you want that the last url rewrites to `test.php?success` instead of the other file. There is a easy fix for this problem, we simple swap the 2 lines of rewrite rules so the longer one is listed first

Resulting `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/success/ test.php?success

RewriteRule ^test/ test.php
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule **^test/$ test.php**

RewriteRule **^test/success/$ test.php?success**

it will also work for you. If you don't need slash after success then you can remove it. And you have need to open test/success
You must need to close .htaccess rewrite url on which you want to redirect your url.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^test/([a-zA-Z0-9-]*) test.php?subpage=$1    [NC]
```

And you can have links like: /test/*put-here-any-text*/

```
test.php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['subpage']) )
    echo $_GET['subpage'];
else
{
    echo "nothing is set";
}
?>
```